# How to install bundles to remote locations OSGI Equinox

Tags: osgi, equinox, osgi-bundle

I am using the OSGI framework, mainly Equinox.

I know how to get bundles working on a local system.

```
osgi> install file:path/to/file
```

or if theyre in a remote location then:

```
osgi> install http://ip_addressordomain:filelocation
```

How do I have it so I can have my osgi console running on Machine A and from it start and run a bundle on Machine B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of options. You can tell Equinox to create the console on a TCP/IP port rather than using standard input, for example:

```
java -jar org.eclipse.osgi_blah.jar -console 9999
```

... and now you can telnet into the machine on port 9999. Bear in mind however that this is very insecure, so not something you should do in a production environment.

Alternatively you can use the [Felix Web Console](https://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-web-console.html), which will give you a full web-based management console for the OSGi framework.

Comment: Thanks once again, I only started using the OSGI framework yesterday so am still picking up the jist of things, all your suggestions have been very helpful along with [this post](http://njbartlett.name/2010/03/07/osgi-and-how-it-got-that-way.html).